# Why doesn't wpmu_new_user work from a plugin when it does from theme?

Tags: multisite

So here's a simple test function that should send an email (just want to get it working first before I work on other functionality) when a new user is created on the multisite installation. The email should be sent when a user signs up from wp-signup.php and clicks the activation link from their email.

```
function test_wpmu_new_user( $user_id ) {
    wp_mail( 'me@myemail.com', 'The subject', 'The body' );
}
add_action( 'wpmu_new_user', 'test_wpmu_new_user' );
```

It **works** from a theme's functions.php, but **not** from a simple plugin with nothing else in it.

It also works when I hardcode it into ms-functions.php where another function, `newuser_notify_siteadmin` lives, which also fires on `wpmu_new_user`. Obviously I don't want to hardcode it.

And lastly, it **does** work from the same plugin file, but only when the new user is created by the super admin in the WP admin. I need it to work for a self registering user however. Trac states:

> This function runs when a user self-registers as well as when a Super
>   Admin creates a new user. Hook to 'wpmu_new_user' for events that
>   should affect all new users, but only on Multisite (otherwise use
>   'user_register').

Is it a priority issue? Do I need to load it on a specific hook?

Comment: It works for me.  Are you sure you are not defining test_wpmu_new_user() in multiple places?  For example if you are using that function in the theme AND in the plugin.  In the plugin jusr change the name, e.g. plugin_wpmu_new_user()

Comment: Did you network-activate the plugin?